# Show that if $X$ is $T_0$ and $T_3$, then $X$ is regular.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Show that if $X$ is $T_0$ and $T_3$, then $X$ is regular.

I need to show that $T_0$ and $T_3$ implies that $X$ is $T_1$. So let $a,b \in X$ s.t $a \ne b$. As $X$ is $T_0$ there exists nbhd of $a$ namely $U_a$ such that $a \in U_a$ and $b \notin U_a$.

Now since $U_a$ is open $U_a^c$ is closed and $b \in U_a^c$.

Since $X$ is $T_3$ we can find open nbhd's for $a$ and $U_a^c$, but $b \in U_a^c$ so we can find disjoint open nbhd's for $a$ and $b$ implying that the space is also $T_1$.

Am I correct here? I think that I can use the complement of $U_a$ to find the nbhd's for $a$ and $b$ such that they don't belong to their repsective nbhd's.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works. $T_0$ gives an assymetric separation that the $T_3$ property can fix, straight to Hausdorff even:

If $a \neq b$, we have $U_a$ so that $a \in U_a$, $b \notin U_a$ WLOG. ($T_0$ just gives us one open set, not two, but you don't know a priori where each point lies, after renaming we can assume $a$ is in the open set).

Then we separate $a$ and the closed set $X\setminus U_a$ by disjoint open sets $a \in V_a$, $X\setminus U_a \subseteq W_b$ with $V_a \cap W_b = \emptyset$. Then $b \in W_b$ and $a \in U_a \cap V_a$ are open and disjoint neighbourhoods of $a$ and $b$ and $X$ is even $T_2$ (and hence $T_1$ a fortiori).